# Why isn't this expression for a ReportViewer field field working?

Tags: reportviewer, vb.net-2010, report-viewer2010

I have a calculated field in one of my reports:

```
=IIf(Fields!Log_Total.Value > 0, (Fields!Log_Cost.Value + Fields!Labor_Cost.Value + Fields!Part_Cost.Value + Fields!Other_Costs.Value) / Fields!Log_Total.Value, 0)
```

As far as everything I have seen this is the correct syntax for what I am trying to accomplish, which is basically, check for zero, if not zero, add these and divide by this. When I run the report the field just comes out as #ERR. All the fields above are a part of the dataset, which I know is working fine. Please help

Comment: Where's the regular expression? Why have you tagged your question `regex`?

Answer (score 0):

The expression itself seems to be fine. Otherwise you'd be getting an error right away when launchung the report.

Do one or more fields in the sum have the value `null` in the data source? In that case, the sum might not work.

Are you sure all the values actually have numeric types? Make sure that none of them is returned as a `string` or something from the database.

Comment: All the fields are generated from a sql query where I am using isnull. So no nulls should be coming through, but most of the time the values for these will be 0.00.

Comment: Yes I just double checked, everything I am working with is being passed back in decimal format

Comment: This question may sound dumb - is this part of a grid tablix? Or is it within a simple `TextBox`? Could it be that the report element doesn't know about the data source, so that you'd have to set it explicitly? What I mean is: For a tablix, there's a property for the data source. Every row in the tablix represents one item in the data set. For text boxes, your code wouldn't work unless they are in a container that again takes a data source and replicates its content for each row. Otherwise, you'd have to use something like `First(Fields!XYZ.Value, "DataSetName")` in your expression.

Comment: Definitely not a dumb question, I have run into that issue before, but I don't believe that's the case for this one. It is a text box field that is nested in a tablix that DOES have the datasource referenced. I dunno if the level of nesting matters here but it goes like this: Tablix > TablixRow > Rectangle > TextBox

Comment: What happens if you output one of the field in the textbox? Does that work?

Comment: Yes. All the fields that are referenced here are outputting correctly in other text boxes. so "=Fields!Other_Costs.Value" works fine by itself.